# Get value of first input, starting at fourth

Tags: jquery, html

I have four input elements

```
    <div class="TxtLeft" style="margin-bottom: 6px"> Screens </div>
    <input id='Quote_Screens_Quan_1' class='' type="Tiny" placeholder="Qty" >
    <input id='Quote_Screens_Desc_1' class='' type="Text" placeholder="Screen Description" >
    <input id='Quote_Screens_Unit_1' class='' type="CurrencySmallTextBox" placeholder="Unit Price " >
    <input id='Quote_Screens_Line_1' class='Rox' type="CurrencySmallTextBox" placeholder='Total' >
```

An event is triggered on keyup from the fourth input ( Class of Rox ) , What I want to find is the value of the first input. I can find the previous value with my code below but I somehow need to specify a number of elements to count back to.

```
$('.Rox').keyup(function() {    
    var x = $(this).prev().val() ; 
    // This gets me the value of 'Quote_Screens_Unit_1' but I need 'Quote_Screens_Quan_1'   
});
```

Comment: Do you just need the first input, or do you specifically need code that says "Count back `n` inputs"? If it's *always* the first, you can grab the first input sibling by doing `var x = $(this).siblings('input').first();`

Comment: That works thanks, Can I specify 'n' inputs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### To count back `n` inputs within the same parent:

https://jsfiddle.net/n48hdqqc/

```
var countBack = 1;

$(".Rox").keyup(function() { 
    //Get the index of .Rox in relation to inputs only
    var thisIndex = $(this).index('input');

    //Store all inputs (including .Rox)
    var $inputs = $(this).parent().children('input');

    //Use .eq to target our desired element in the container
    var x = $inputs.eq(thisIndex-countBack).val();

    alert(x);
});
```

You can manipulate `countBack` to determine how many elements back you'd like to go.

This will look for `n` sibling inputs before `.Rox`. So 0 would be the value of `.Rox`, 1 would be `Quote_Screens_Unit_1`, 2 would be `Quote_Screens_Desc_1`, and so on.

---

### To get input by occurrence within parent:

```
var inputIndex = 1;

$(".Rox").keyup(function() { 

    //Store all inputs (including .Rox)
    var $inputs = $(this).parent().children('input');

    //Get specifically the second input in this container (index 1)
    var x = $inputs.eq(inputIndex).val();

    alert(x);
});
```

Change `inputIndex` to grab a specific input. Remember, `.eq()` indexes start with 0, so `var inputIndex = 1;` will get the second input, and so on.

---

### To get the first sibling input:

```
$(".Rox").keyup(function() { 
    var x = $(this).siblings().first().val();
    alert(x);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of [siblings()](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) and [first()](https://api.jquery.com/first/) to get the value of the first input:

```js
$('.Rox').keyup(function() {    
    var x = $(this).siblings('input').first().val();
    console.log(x);  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="TxtLeft" style="margin-bottom: 6px"> Screens </div>
<input id='Quote_Screens_Quan_1' class='' type="Tiny" placeholder="Qty" >
<input id='Quote_Screens_Desc_1' class='' type="Text" placeholder="Screen Description" >
<input id='Quote_Screens_Unit_1' class='' type="CurrencySmallTextBox" placeholder="Unit Price " >
<input id='Quote_Screens_Line_1' class='Rox' type="CurrencySmallTextBox" placeholder='Total' >
```

Answer (score 0):

This greatly depends on your overall markup and if you have any containing elements wrapping these (as that would allow you to encapsulate your queries to parent containers to avoid targeting the wrong element).

**Consider using the ID**

The `id` attribute is by definition unique, so you could easily resolve this by simply always targeting your specific input using that attribute :

```
$('.Rox').keyup(function() {    
    // This will always access your specific quantity
    var x = $('#Quote_Screens_Quan_1').val(); 
});
```

**Consider targeting a sibling**

jQuery features a [`siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) function that can be useful if you want to access a particular sibling element using a certain selector :

```
$('.Rox').keyup(function() {    
    // This will give you the first input sibling from this one
    var x = $(this).siblings('input:first').val();
});
```

This uses the [`:first`](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) selector to target the first element, however if you needed another (i.e. 2nd, 3rd, etc.), you could use the [`:eq(n)`](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector to access that element by its index :

```
// This will give you the first input sibling from this one
var first = $(this).siblings('input:eq(0)').val();
var second = $(this).siblings('input:eq(1)').val();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will have a great many blocks of the four inputs so I want to do this dynamically rather than referencing the id ,

Comment: I'd highly recommend grouping these sets of four elements within a parent container if you are planning on doing that. This would make it much easier to handle targeting the element that you need. You could also consider using either CSS classes or HTML data-* attributes to make targeting a bit easier (i.e. `data-type="quantity"` and then using that to find your specific element).

Comment: if there is only 1 item with a specific class within a group of siblings, you can use .siblings() or .prevUntil() and target that class.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to give the input you are trying to reach a specific class or id, and then search for it with [.siblings()](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) or [.prevUntil()](https://api.jquery.com/prevUntil/)

```
$(this).siblings('#Quote_Screens_Quan_1').val();
$(this).prevUntil('#Quote_Screens_Quan_1').val();
```